# creating jar file of maven projects with netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, maven, jar

I am using netbeans to work on a project. I am using svn, so that I can commit to newer versions and revert to an older version in case I mess up. Now I want to create a jar file of this project but the build tab in the project properties does not display the packaging option, it only displays one option and that is of 'compile'.

If I create a new project (Java Application) it does show the packaging option and then I can easily create a jar file, but this maven project that I am working on does not work like this.

Please suggest me a way to create jar file out of my maven project.

Thanks,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Open `cmd` (if you are on Windows) or any shell (if you are on Linux)
2. Navigate to your project directory (use `cd` command)
3. Run `mvn clean package` there.

Your jar will be in `<project dir>/target`.

Answer (score 16):

Based on @yatskevich answer, you could go to your NetBeans **Project Properties > Actions** and add *package* to the **Execute Goals** of the following Actions:

- Build project
- Clean and Build project
- Build with dependencies
- Plus any other you feel should also package

I did this on NetBeans 7.2.1

PS: this will create the JAR on every change you make, so choose wisely where to add *package*. I don't mind it building a JAR for small projects on every build.

Comment: I'm having a difficult time getting this to work on "Run". When I choose "Run" in NetBeans its not creating the Jar first, even though I have package as the first action. Any ideas why?

Comment: what else is it doing? do you get a different behavior if you run `mvn package` from the console?

Answer (score 1):

Include `maven-assembly-plugin` plugin in your `.pom` file. It will instruct Maven to assemble your application with all it's dependencies.

Later when you will build your Netbeans project you will see your newly builded `jar` with all it's dependencies.

```
<build>
   <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                    <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.my.class</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>                         
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

Check out to learn more about creating Jar file with Maven: https://javatutorial.net/create-java-jar-file-with-maven